# Does Entity Framework Update Foreign Key Values Automatically?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, foreign-keys

This is a very simple issue, and I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer. My setup is simple, two tables with a Foreign Key to connect them. I'm able to successfully update both tables wtih EF, but the ID value from the Parent table isn't populated when I call SaveChanges. **Do I have to manually assign the ID value from the Parent table to the appropriate property in the Child table to get the Foreign Key to be populated in the database?** It seems odd that I would have to do this as it seems like it should be automatic, but I am new to EF. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does keep these in sync, with limitations. [Here's an explanation of what's involved.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) You do not have to manually assign IDs.

You don't give enough information in your question to solve your problem, but here are a few things to check:

- Are the entities in the same context?
- If you're using POCOs, [this can get complicated](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/). You might have turned off [AutoDetectChanges](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/5/7/entityframework_performance_and_autodetectchanges).
- Try a simple test app. Perhaps some other code in your app is interfering with this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Craig.  In response to the things you said I should check:  * The entities are in the same context  * I'm not using POCOs  * I'll try creating a test app, but my setup is already fairly simple.  I'll also check the links.

Comment: If you create a test app, you can update your answer with your code.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. It was a simple mistake that the weekend break helped me to identify.

Comment: @OneSource would be nice if you posted your fix!

Comment: @Shumi, it's been a while since I posted this question and I don't remember how I resolved this. Sorry! FYI, due to various issues with Entity Framework, I have decided to switch to Dapper as my ORM of choice.